# Repetition in Fibonacci series with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a method that prints the first `n` numbers `fibonacci` series using recursion.
I do not want to write the method then create a separate loop after the method to print out the first `n` `fibonacci` series. I tried using `try` and `finally` block since I know the `finally` statement will always be executed. The `fibonacci` series output works fine but keeps repeating. Is it possible to stop the repetition?

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    try:
        fib = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
        return fib
    finally:
        print("F{} = {}".format(n, fib))
    
fibonacci(6)
```

output

```
F2 = 1
F3 = 2
F2 = 1
F4 = 3
F2 = 1
F3 = 2
F5 = 5
F2 = 1
F3 = 2
F2 = 1
F4 = 3
F6 = 8
```

Comment: "I do not want to write the method then create a separate loop after the method to print out the first n fibonacci series" why?

Comment: The recursion force you to recompute 2 values recursively at each stage. So putting your print statement within your recursive function displays some stuff you don't want to see. I would generate the values and display the result elsewhere.

Comment: so that it is. you can try with dp memo. setting to dict, then print dict.

Comment: @MetallimaX Sounds helpful. I could simply form a separate loop outside. Just wondering if there's a better way

Comment: @deadshot It's something everyone does. Just trying to see if there is a better way

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what `finally:` does.  It will execute in every recursive call, even if the `try` fails (which seems rather useless anyway -- it will only really fail if you pass in invalid input) or `return`s.

Comment: I'd recommand you to have a look at functools.lru_cache to save some computation as Fibonacci series can consume a lot of resources for not as high numbers ;)

Comment: A better algorithm is to return two values, one of which is the current input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of default parameters like this:

```
def fibonacci(n, a=1, b=1):
    if n==0:
        return;
    else:
        print(a)
        fibonaci(n-1, b, a+b)

fibonacci(10)

Output:
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly minimal change to your code will avoid the *unnecessary* recursion, and then only print what (I hope) you want.

```py
def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 1, 1
    try:
        nxt, fib = fibonacci(n-1)
        return nxt+fib, nxt
    finally:
        print("F{} = {}".format(n, fib))
    
fibonacci(6)
```

Output:

```
F1 = 1
F2 = 1
F3 = 2
F4 = 3
F5 = 5
F6 = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to have a non local value to remember whether a number has already be printed. A simple way is to use a closure and a locally defined function:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    done = -1
    def fibo(n):
        nonlocal done
        if n <= 1:
            fib = n
        else:
            fib = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
        if n > done:
            print("F{} = {}".format(n, fib))
            done = n
        return fib
    fibo(n)
```

You can now do:

```
>>> fibonacci(6)
F1 = 1
F2 = 1
F3 = 2
F4 = 3
F5 = 5
F6 = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your function a generator and use unpacking in the print statement (with a new line separator if needed):

```
def fibo(n,a=0,b=1):
    yield a
    if n>1:
        yield from fibo(n-1,b,a+b)

print(*fibo(10),sep="\n")

0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

You can also use the print function inside the function but that is now how functions should operate:

```
def fibo(n,a=0,b=1):
    print(a)
    if n>1:fibo(n-1,b,a+b)

fibo(10)
```

*BTW, the modern version of the Fibonacci sequence starts at zero*